# Insert a new row using JpaRepository from self-made util in java

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm so new with SpringBoot, this is the way why i need your help.

I have following entity class which I want to insert in table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@DynamicInsert
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "promotion_id")
    private Long promotion_id;

    @Column(name = "period")
    private String period;

    @Column(name = "limit_amount")
    private Long limit_amount;
}
```

I have multiple objects of Test and I want to insert it to the table. For this I have created a repo class:

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, Long> {

    List<TestEntity> findFirstById (Long id);
}
```

And after that i created other util-class for easy-work with my test:

```
@Service
public class TestUtil {

    @Autowired
    private TestRepository testRepository;

    public void InsertRow(Long promotion_id, String period, Long amount) {
        TestEntity tab = new TestEntity();

        tab.setPromotion_id(promotion_id);
        tab.setPeriod(period);
        tab.setLimit_amount(amount);

        testRepository.save(tab);
    }
}
```

And finally i create small test to check how it works:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestContainerApplication.class)
public class TestExample extends ContainersEnviroment {

    private static Long promotion_id = 1L;
    private static String period = "MONTH";
    private static Long amount = 100L;

    @Autowired
    public TestRepository TestRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        TestUtil util = new TestUtil();
        util.InsertRow(promotion_id, period, amount);
    }

    @Test
    public void TestExample() {
        //code
}
```

And I use TestContainers with test database from my server using application.yaml

Problem:
When I try to insert something inside my table, i have NPE

```
Cannot invoke "ru.at.database.dao.TestRepository.save(Object)" because "this.TestRepository" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "ru.at.database.dao.TestRepository.save(Object)" because "this.TestRepository" is null
```

I think that i cant Autowired TestRepository from @Test, but i don't know how to fix it.

I try to declare @DataJpaTest in my TestClass, but it still doesn't work, cause i have another error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to replace DataSource with an embedded database for tests. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath or tune the replace attribute of @AutoConfigureTestDatabase.
```